# How do you create a moving window calculation in SQL for a time series? (not averages)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am working with data where I need to use a calculation that is supposed to reference a previously calculated value in the previous row.

For example, take this dataset:

```
SELECT 
    generate_series('2015-01-01', '2019-12-01', '1 month'::interval)::date AS dates,
    generate_series(1,60) AS nums;
```

There's are `NULL` values starting at `2019-03-01`.

I'd like to write a calculation on another column that fills it in based off the previous row, that is derived from that same calculation. So I tried to use some `lag()` functions. But after a while it turns to `NULL`, probably because the previous calculation is also null.

```
with
mynumbers AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series('2015-01-01', '2025-12-01', '1 month'::interval)::date AS dates,
        generate_series(1,50) AS nums),
mynumbers_lag AS (
    SELECT *, lag(nums) OVER (ORDER BY dates ASC) AS previous1
    FROM mynumbers)
SELECT dates, nums, previous1, (coalesce(nums,previous1)+lag(coalesce(nums,previous1), 5) OVER (ORDER BY dates ASC))*4 AS moving_calculation FROM mynumbers_lag;
```

The result starts to deviate from what I'd like it to be at `2019-03-01`. I'd like my calculation to continue all the way through the table. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Edit: borrowing unutbu's table.. I want to yield this:

```
|      dates | nums | previous1 | moving_calculation |
|------------+------+-----------+--------------------|
| 2015-01-01 |    1 |           |                    |
| 2015-02-01 |    2 |         1 |                    |
| 2015-03-01 |    3 |         2 |                    |
| 2015-04-01 |    4 |         3 |                    |
| 2015-05-01 |    5 |         4 |                    |
| 2015-06-01 |    6 |         5 |                 28 |
| 2015-07-01 |    7 |         6 |                 36 |
| 2015-08-01 |    8 |         7 |                 44 |
| 2015-09-01 |    9 |         8 |                 52 |
| 2015-10-01 |   10 |         9 |                 60 |
...
| 2018-12-01 |   50 |        49 |                364 |
| 2019-01-01 |   50 |        49 |                372 |
| 2019-02-01 |   50 |        49 |                380 |
| 2019-03-01 |   50 |        49 |                388 |
| 2019-04-01 |   50 |        49 |               1744 | 
| 2019-05-01 |   50 |        49 |               7172 |
| 2019-06-01 |      |           |              28888 |
| 2019-07-01 |      |           |             117104 |
| 2019-08-01 |      |           |             475392 |
| 2019-09-01 |      |           |            1930256 |
```

On `2019-04-01`, the `1744` is calculated from `(388+48)*4`. The `388` is one
cell from the previously calculated value because `nums` is NULL. Eventually,
starting on `2018-07-01`, both `nums` are NULL, so it will calculating using
only from `moving_calculations` (values `380` and `7172`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in the `moving_calculation` column (denoted `m0` below) depend on
prior values in the same column.  They are defined by a recurrence
relation. There might even be a closed-form formula for `m0`. You might want to
ask a question on [Mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you wish to find a closed-form
formula.  If we knew the closed-form formula, clearly computing values in
Postgresql would be a breeze.

However, if we regard this problem as a programming problem, then I believe the calculation -- if it is to be done in Postgresql -- is most easily expressed using [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).
The calculation sort of feels like the calculation of [Fibonacci numbers](https://gist.github.com/komamitsu/c2a5c46a22d765df5aa2).

```
WITH RECURSIVE r(a, b) AS (
  SELECT 0::int, 1::int
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b, a + b FROM r WHERE b < 50
)
SELECT a, b FROM r;
```

yields

```
|  a |  b |
|----+----|
|  0 |  1 |
|  1 |  1 |
|  1 |  2 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  3 |  5 |
|  5 |  8 |
|  8 | 13 |
| 13 | 21 |
| 21 | 34 |
| 34 | 55 |
```

If you understand the use of `WITH RECURSIVE` in that Fibonacci example, then I believe you'll see the solution below 
is merely an extension of the same idea.

```
WITH RECURSIVE r(dates, nums, prev, m0, m1, m2, m3) AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('2019-02-01'::date, 50::numeric, 47::numeric, 388::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric)) AS t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (dates + '1 month'::interval)::date
        , m0
        , coalesce(m3, prev+1)
        , (m0+coalesce(m3, prev+1))*4
        , m0
        , m1
        , m2
    FROM r
    WHERE dates <= '2020-01-01'
)
SELECT * FROM r
```

yields

```
|      dates |       nums |     prev |         m0 |         m1 |        m2 |        m3 |
|------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------|
| 2019-02-01 |         50 |       47 |        388 |            |           |           |
| 2019-03-01 |        388 |       48 |       1744 |        388 |           |           |
| 2019-04-01 |       1744 |       49 |       7172 |       1744 |       388 |           |
| 2019-05-01 |       7172 |       50 |      28888 |       7172 |      1744 |       388 |
| 2019-06-01 |      28888 |      388 |     117104 |      28888 |      7172 |      1744 |
| 2019-07-01 |     117104 |     1744 |     475392 |     117104 |     28888 |      7172 |
| 2019-08-01 |     475392 |     7172 |    1930256 |     475392 |    117104 |     28888 |
| 2019-09-01 |    1930256 |    28888 |    7836576 |    1930256 |    475392 |    117104 |
| 2019-10-01 |    7836576 |   117104 |   31814720 |    7836576 |   1930256 |    475392 |
| 2019-11-01 |   31814720 |   475392 |  129160448 |   31814720 |   7836576 |   1930256 |
| 2019-12-01 |  129160448 |  1930256 |  524362816 |  129160448 |  31814720 |   7836576 |
| 2020-01-01 |  524362816 |  7836576 | 2128797568 |  524362816 | 129160448 |  31814720 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2128797568 | 31814720 | 8642449152 | 2128797568 | 524362816 | 129160448 |
```

To combine this table with the original table, use `UNION`:

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT *, (nums+prev)*4 AS m0, NULL::numeric AS m1, NULL::numeric AS m2, NULL::numeric AS m3
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            , lag(nums, 3) OVER (ORDER BY dates ASC) AS prev 
        FROM (
        SELECT
            generate_series('2015-01-01', '2025-12-01', '1 month'::interval)::date AS dates,
            generate_series(1,50)::numeric AS nums) t
        ) t2
    WHERE nums IS NOT NULL
), last_row AS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable
    WHERE nums IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY dates DESC
    LIMIT 1 
)
SELECT * FROM mytable
UNION (
    WITH RECURSIVE r(dates, nums, prev, m0, m1, m2, m3) AS (
        SELECT * FROM last_row
        UNION ALL
        SELECT (dates + '1 month'::interval)::date
            , m0
            , coalesce(m3, prev+1)
            , (m0+coalesce(m3, prev+1))*4
            , m0
            , m1
            , m2
        FROM r
        WHERE dates <= '2020-01-01')
    SELECT * FROM r)
ORDER BY dates
```

which yields

```
|      dates |       nums |     prev |         m0 |         m1 |        m2 |        m3 |
|------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------|
| 2015-01-01 |          1 |          |            |            |           |           |
| 2015-02-01 |          2 |          |            |            |           |           |
| 2015-03-01 |          3 |          |            |            |           |           |
| 2015-04-01 |          4 |        1 |         20 |            |           |           |
| 2015-05-01 |          5 |        2 |         28 |            |           |           |
| 2015-06-01 |          6 |        3 |         36 |            |           |           |
| 2015-07-01 |          7 |        4 |         44 |            |           |           |
| 2015-08-01 |          8 |        5 |         52 |            |           |           |
| 2015-09-01 |          9 |        6 |         60 |            |           |           |
| 2015-10-01 |         10 |        7 |         68 |            |           |           |
| 2015-11-01 |         11 |        8 |         76 |            |           |           |
| 2015-12-01 |         12 |        9 |         84 |            |           |           |
| 2016-01-01 |         13 |       10 |         92 |            |           |           |
| 2016-02-01 |         14 |       11 |        100 |            |           |           |
| 2016-03-01 |         15 |       12 |        108 |            |           |           |
| 2016-04-01 |         16 |       13 |        116 |            |           |           |
| 2016-05-01 |         17 |       14 |        124 |            |           |           |
| 2016-06-01 |         18 |       15 |        132 |            |           |           |
| 2016-07-01 |         19 |       16 |        140 |            |           |           |
| 2016-08-01 |         20 |       17 |        148 |            |           |           |
| 2016-09-01 |         21 |       18 |        156 |            |           |           |
| 2016-10-01 |         22 |       19 |        164 |            |           |           |
| 2016-11-01 |         23 |       20 |        172 |            |           |           |
| 2016-12-01 |         24 |       21 |        180 |            |           |           |
| 2017-01-01 |         25 |       22 |        188 |            |           |           |
| 2017-02-01 |         26 |       23 |        196 |            |           |           |
| 2017-03-01 |         27 |       24 |        204 |            |           |           |
| 2017-04-01 |         28 |       25 |        212 |            |           |           |
| 2017-05-01 |         29 |       26 |        220 |            |           |           |
| 2017-06-01 |         30 |       27 |        228 |            |           |           |
| 2017-07-01 |         31 |       28 |        236 |            |           |           |
| 2017-08-01 |         32 |       29 |        244 |            |           |           |
| 2017-09-01 |         33 |       30 |        252 |            |           |           |
| 2017-10-01 |         34 |       31 |        260 |            |           |           |
| 2017-11-01 |         35 |       32 |        268 |            |           |           |
| 2017-12-01 |         36 |       33 |        276 |            |           |           |
| 2018-01-01 |         37 |       34 |        284 |            |           |           |
| 2018-02-01 |         38 |       35 |        292 |            |           |           |
| 2018-03-01 |         39 |       36 |        300 |            |           |           |
| 2018-04-01 |         40 |       37 |        308 |            |           |           |
| 2018-05-01 |         41 |       38 |        316 |            |           |           |
| 2018-06-01 |         42 |       39 |        324 |            |           |           |
| 2018-07-01 |         43 |       40 |        332 |            |           |           |
| 2018-08-01 |         44 |       41 |        340 |            |           |           |
| 2018-09-01 |         45 |       42 |        348 |            |           |           |
| 2018-10-01 |         46 |       43 |        356 |            |           |           |
| 2018-11-01 |         47 |       44 |        364 |            |           |           |
| 2018-12-01 |         48 |       45 |        372 |            |           |           |
| 2019-01-01 |         49 |       46 |        380 |            |           |           |
| 2019-02-01 |         50 |       47 |        388 |            |           |           |
| 2019-03-01 |        388 |       48 |       1744 |        388 |           |           |
| 2019-04-01 |       1744 |       49 |       7172 |       1744 |       388 |           |
| 2019-05-01 |       7172 |       50 |      28888 |       7172 |      1744 |       388 |
| 2019-06-01 |      28888 |      388 |     117104 |      28888 |      7172 |      1744 |
| 2019-07-01 |     117104 |     1744 |     475392 |     117104 |     28888 |      7172 |
| 2019-08-01 |     475392 |     7172 |    1930256 |     475392 |    117104 |     28888 |
| 2019-09-01 |    1930256 |    28888 |    7836576 |    1930256 |    475392 |    117104 |
| 2019-10-01 |    7836576 |   117104 |   31814720 |    7836576 |   1930256 |    475392 |
| 2019-11-01 |   31814720 |   475392 |  129160448 |   31814720 |   7836576 |   1930256 |
| 2019-12-01 |  129160448 |  1930256 |  524362816 |  129160448 |  31814720 |   7836576 |
| 2020-01-01 |  524362816 |  7836576 | 2128797568 |  524362816 | 129160448 |  31814720 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2128797568 | 31814720 | 8642449152 | 2128797568 | 524362816 | 129160448 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I may have not been clear in my question... I'm looking for a way for the calculation to continue throughout `moving_calculation`, but to return the last number. The `coalesce` is meant to take `previous1`, but `previous1` is intended to keep calculating. That is, at some point, it will be based off previous values of `previous1`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you modify your post (above) to include the output you are looking for? (I'm not grasping what "it will be based off previous values of `previous1`" means.)

Comment: Editted! Thanks for taking a look... Please let me know if it requires clarification. I don't know how to efficiently remove your other columns so I left them blank.